# Vuejs not refreshing the component after redirection

Tags: vue.js

I have a form in one component. After the submit-ion  i am redirecting the view to the list where new submit should display.
But is doesn't. 
I have to refresh the page and then the change will appear.
How do I instruct the page to reload the content after it is updated

Currently, in order to change the route, I am using:

```
methods: { 
    submitMovie () { 
        movieService.submitMovie(this.newMovie)
            .then( this.$router.push('/movies'))
            .catch( e=> { this.errors.push(e) }) 
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share your code if you want help debugging the problem. Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How exactly are you _"redirecting the view"_? Are you using vue-router?

Comment: methods: {
        submitMovie () {
            movieService.submitMovie(this.newMovie)
            .then( this.$router.push('/movies'))
            .catch( e=> {
                this.errors.push(e)
            })
        },

Comment: You need to provide a function to your `then` call, eg `.then(() => { this.$router.push('/movies') })`

Answer (score 0):

.then(() => { this.$router.push('/movies') })

Thanks Phill. 
I was trying to solve this for about 2 days. 
All it needed was a function inside next. 
Why I still don't understand but I will research about the issue

Thanks Again